# I want to create a speech regognition program

Tags: javascript

I’m 14 and I have a brief knowledge of JavaScript but I’m very intrigued in programming, I would like to create a program that can start and stop a stopwatch based on when a person’s speech/talk of a convention is completed. I don’t know how this would be done, that’s what I want to know, I don’t want to know the exact code just the main way this could be done. I would like to have it potentially run on an iPhone.  Or a computer which is running the microphones and speakers

To be more clear
A person would walk on stage, start talking, (there would be other voices as part of a discussion) the stopwatch starts, the person finishes his speech and the stopwatch stops. There would also be a chairman who introduces the speakers which does not need to be timed

Thank you for any advice you could give me.

Comment: I'm not sure how you would detect when the person has finished speaking. It sounds like a machine learning problem, if that's the case [fast.ai](https://www.fast.ai/) will get you up to scratch on that. It looks like the common terminology for this is [voice activity detection](https://github.com/jtkim-kaist/VAD) so I would start there.

Comment: Ok I will look into that, thank you

Answer (score 0):

You are not going to achieve this in JavaScript alone. Programs like Alexa and Siri capture the audio and send it to a speech recognition server for processing. To do it on a computer you would need to be running some sort of speech recognition engine to process the audio for you.

Comment: Is there any way to do it by detecting when a speaker gets on the stage with some sort of sensor I could buy?

Comment: Just fudge it by having a friend behind the curtain push a button for you.

Comment: I already do that, that’s what I want to make the program for. I just have no idea how to do the detection of the start and end of the speech

Comment: [vad](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/2386/libraries-for-voice-activity-detection-not-speech-recognition) libs